# Whats wrong with my program? Code provided

Tags: java

My code won't work. I'm trying to make a calculator for `x^(3/2)`.

It tells me I need ";" at `double TwoThirdPower(double A)`. At the parenthesis.

```
public class JFindAlphabet {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] Theory) {

    JWaffles MyWaffles = new JWaffles();
    MyWaffles.ProgramHeading();
    double Glasses;
    Glasses = 1.0   ;

    double TwoThirdPower(double A) {
            double x;
            x = 0.0;
            while ( Math.sqrt(x*x*x) < A ) {
                x = x + 0.0001;
            }
            return x;
    }
    System.out.println("\n\t" + Glasses + " to the two thirds power = "+ TwoThirdPower(Glasses) );

  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: If you fix your indentation, it will be clear what the error is.

Comment: It's due to sloppy coding pure and simple. Take care when you code, line up your braces, watch your spelling, compile often and fix all complilation errors before adding new code. That will prevent these types of errors from happening.

Comment: On top of all the other problems, why don't you just replace the body of TwoThirdPower with `return Math.cbrt(A*A);`?

Answer (score 2):

The function

```
double TwoThirdPower(double A)
```

is declared inside

```
public static void main(String[] Theory)
```

You need to close the definition of Main first with `}`

Being careful about indenting braces (or using an editor that does that for you) will help prevent this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare another method in a method.

Answer (score 1):

> double TwoThirdPower(double A)

is a method declaration in the middle of a method body.  Such things are not allowed in Java.

Move the `TwoThirdPower` method definition outside the `main` method, so `main` would read

```
public static void main(String[] Theory) {
  JWaffles MyWaffles = new JWaffles();

  MyWaffles.ProgramHeading();

  double Glasses = 1.0   ;

  System.out.println("\n\t" + Glasses
    + " to the two thirds power = "+ TwoThirdPower(Glasses) );
 }
```

and then that method would be followed by `TwoThirdPower`.